# Can I create a button to enable javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to create a button to enable javascript if a user doesn't have it enabled?

If not, is there another way to enable javascript in the user's browser automatically when they visit our website?

Failing that, can I access the user's browser settings with permission and then enable javascript?

Comment: No, disabling javascript is a safety option built into browsers, allowing sites to turn it on automatically would be horrible.

Comment: No, the best you could do is use a `<noscript>` tag to give users clear instructions that it needs to be on, and link to some documentation.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: To be fair, he said "with user permission". I think the best you can do is, if Javascript is crucial to your website, have an early intercept page that displays a warning inside <noscript>, and uses javascript to immediately forward users to the main page. If the user disabled javascript themselves, they will likely know how to re-enable it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

If a user has disabled JavaScript then there is no way for a website to do anything (other then provide instructions (e.g. in `<noscript>`)) to "help" them turn it on.

Given that people disabling JS are, increasingly, using third party tools (such as NoScript) to do so, providing instructions isn't likely to be helpful anyway. If a user has disabled JavaScript, then it is safe to assume that they understand the consequences of doing so and are capable of finding the On switch for themselves.

JavaScript *can* fail for other reasons though (such as a network problem while the JS file was downloading), so always be [progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered using a `<noscript>` tag?

```
<noscript>
     <div class="bigRedWarningBoxInMiddleOfScreen">
        Enable javascript pretty please
      </div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question does it... just saying

Comment: I saw it somewhere, When i use some sites, It asks me Run this time and Never run for this site option in my chrome window, it runs the javascript game/app when i click on run this time. How to create that or something like that, I think thats called a user permission.

Answer (score 6):

No, if web pages could control the security setting of browsers, we'd be DOOMED!

Comment: True. I'll give you my upvote if you argue why we would be doomed.

Comment: Anything attemping to block malware could be disabled remotely.

Comment: he's got 55.3k. probably not worth it. :)

Comment: Its not about the author, its about the value of the answer he's providing.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is to check if JavaScript is disabled. If it is you can show a page that guides the user with enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

No but next best thing you could do is:

```
<noscript>
    <div class="alert alert-error">Please enable JavaScript to use this site properly, here's <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">how</a></div>
</noscript>
```

I believe that site detects which browser the user is using and gives directions accordingly.

Some people don't like noscript for some reason so you could do:

```
<div id="noscript">
    <div class="alert alert-error">Please enable JavaScript to use this site properly, here's <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">how</a></div>
</div>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('noscript').style.display = 'none';
```

But this might cause a flicker if your page size is large.

Comment: I saw it somewhere, When i use some sites, It asks me Run this time and Never run for this site option in my chrome window, it runs the javascript game/app when i click on run this time. How to create that or something like that, I think thats called a user permission.

Comment: @Harsimar Are you sure that isn't a JAVA Applet? I get those messages when a JAVA Applet tries to make changes to my computer via the browser. You definitely can't do what you are asking from regular JavaScript, but maybe it's possible from FLash or EMbedded JAVA, not sure.